# Rank over discontinuous blocks of rows

Tags: sql-server, gaps-and-islands, rank

I have the following table Logs:

| Id | Char |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | a |
| 3 | a |
| 4 | b |
| 5 | b |
| 6 | a |
| 7 | a |
| 8 | c |

I want to get something like:

| Id | Char | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 2 | a | 2 |
| 3 | a | 3 |
| 4 | b | 1 |
| 5 | b | 2 |
| 6 | a | 1 |
| 7 | a | 2 |
| 8 | c | 1 |

A MS-SQL-Server query is desirable

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [recursive CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions) to rank the rows based on the previous rows char value. See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SeLcNYKX) for a working example.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT id
    , char
    , 1 AS rank
  FROM tbl
  WHERE id = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.id
    , t.char
    , IIF(t.char = r.char, r.rank+1, 1) AS [rank]
  FROM tbl t
  INNER JOIN CTE r ON r.id = (t.id - 1)
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

Results

| Id | Char | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 2 | a | 2 |
| 3 | a | 3 |
| 4 | b | 1 |
| 5 | b | 2 |
| 6 | a | 1 |
| 7 | a | 2 |
| 8 | c | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use an island-and-gap strategy. We can create groups of consecutive chars by enumerating the whole set and subtract the position within the partition. If there is an interupt, the group will change:

```
SELECT id, char
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id)
     - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY char ORDER BY id) AS grp
FROM t
```

Now it is just a mater of ordering the id's within each group:

```
SELECT id, char
     , ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY id) AS rnk
FROM (  
    SELECT id, char
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) 
          - ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY char ORDER BY id) AS grp
    FROM t
) AS tt;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/P6fN57Sy)